# Couchbase is taking too long in the first response

Tags: c#, couchbase

We have Couchbase running on a CentOS server and we have another server running Windows with the applications (written in .NET). Everything is Ok, but the first response takes about 15-30 seconds. The rest of the calls are fast enough (depends the amount of data)

That's not a big deal because is the first call, but if nobody make a request against that server in 20-30 minutes, the next request take again about 15-30 seconds. Any Idea about which could be the problem?

The version of the .NET SDK is 2.1.3 and I add the connection code

```
var cluster = new Cluster(new ClientConfiguration
{
    Servers = new List<Uri>
        {
            new Uri("url")
        }
});

using (var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("user", "pass"))
{
 try
 {
    var documentList = bucket.Get<T>(docsId);


    return documentList.Select(doc => doc.Value.Value as ICouchbaseObject).ToList();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    Log.Error("Error retrieving documents from couchbase: "+ ex);
 }
}
```

Also, I would like to ask if you could say me recommendations for good material for improve the performance in couchbase (Video, blogs, books...)

Comment: what's taking so long? I'm guessing its not the retrieval from the bucket but rather the connection. Can you add prints or otherwise find out which element is taking so long? which port are you connecting to?

Comment: What makes you think it's CouchBase and not IIS?

Comment: @CodeCaster my first idea was that and I changed the Idle Timeout and the Interval to 0. But I'm still having the same issue. Any other idea why IIS could be causing this problem? Thanks!